# Bâtiment vs bâtisse ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

A google image search shows *bâtisse* to bring up many old stone buildings, while *bâtiment* brings up many newer and larger ones. Both seem to translate to *building* as a noun.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bâtisse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A2tisse) is a usually slightly derogatory way to name any unremarkable building. The building doesn't necessarily need to be old to deserve being qualified a *bâtisse*.

[Bâtiment](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A2timent) is more common and is not derogatory. It apply more to a large building than a small one, has a wider spectrum of meanings (a submarine, carry-over and cruise ship are *bâtiments* but definitively not *bâtisses*). It can also be used to name all the craftsmen and trade around the construction business.

According to google ngram, *Bâtisse* usage frequency is about twenty five times lower than *Bâtiment* frequency. It is however in slight raise since the fifties so one shouldn't state the word is deprecated.

---

[Bâtisse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A2tisse) désigne de manière souvent péjorative une immeuble, une maison, un hangar ou toute construction sans cachet particulier, et pas forcément ancienne.

[Bâtiment](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A2timent) est plus courant. Il n'est pas péjoratif, s'applique plutôt à une construction de grande dimension, a un spectre d'utilisation plus large (un sous-marin, un porte-avions et un navire de croisière sont des bâtiments, certainement pas des bâtisses), et désigne aussi de manière générique les corps de métiers liés à la construction (maisons, immeubles, etc.)

D'après google ngram, la fréquence d'utilisation de bâtisse est environ vingt-cinq fois inférieure à celle de bâtiment. Elle est cependant en légère augmentation depuis les années 1950 , il est donc incorrect d'affirmer que ce mot n'est plus utilisé.

Answer (score 3):

[*Bâtisse*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A2tisse/2) est une altération de l'ancien français *bastissement* basé sur le participe présent de *bâtir*, alors que le [bâtiment](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A2timent) [provient](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/b%C3%A2tir/1) de *bastiment* par l'ancien provençal. C'est surtout par métonymie que les sens se sont développés, les sens originaux concernant l'action de bâtir étant aujourd'hui vieillis ou éteints. [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/b%C3%A2timent/8374/synonyme) les présente généralement comme synonymes, le bâtiment étant [marqué](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/b%C3%A2timent/8374) comme ayant la fonction de *servir d'abri et à isoler*, alors que la bâtisse est [marquée](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/b%C3%A2tisse/8381?q=b%C3%A2tisse#8332) *quelconque et de peu de caractère*, souvent péjorativement (TLFi) : *On démolit la maison qui faisait l'angle de la rue du Bac et qui avait bon air. On la remplacera sans doute par quelque vilaine bâtisse.* (A. France). [Bâtisse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/b%C3%A2tisse/1) apparaît sur Ac.9, comme [bâtiment](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/b%C3%A2timent). *Bâtiment* [semble](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=b%C3%A2tisse%2Cb%C3%A2timent&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cb%C3%A2tisse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cb%C3%A2timent%3B%2Cc0) toujours et de manière constante avoir été davantage utilisé. Au [Québec](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2077848) on emploie en langue courante bâtisse pour bâtiment. Autrement voir aussi [immeuble](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/immeuble/41702?q=immeuble#41607).

Answer (score 1):

No one uses *bâtisse* anymore, it is deprecated if you will :)

On a more serious note, *Batiment* is any building, most probably in a city.

Bâtisse could be used for historical buildings. But it is old french. I have never actually heard anyone say or use it.

Comment: Indeed, I hear "C'est une vieille bâtisse" when visiting historical places or very old building

Comment: After dropping until 1965, *Bâtisse* usage, at least in written French, has steadily increased and is probably more popular nowadays than it has never been. Claiming it is deprecated is then incorrect. See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bâtisse&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=19&smoothing=1

Comment: ... than it has *ever* been, I meant.